# Organisation refusing to train me

Tags: training, australia

**EDIT:** To include comments, to make it more cohesive.

I have been working in my job for four years. My job is a very technical one, and to be 'qualified' to do the job I am doing (according to HR at my organisation), I am actually required to complete a number of SANS courses (these courses are the 'industry standard', for my job).

My organisation is responsible to send its employees on these courses (they cost about $10k AUD each, so there is no way I could afford one myself). I have repeatedly asked for these courses, and have never received one. Every other employee there has gotten one within 6 months of employment (and most have 3-4 under their belts). I however have never received one, despite working for four years.

Last year they were hiring for a managerial role in my area, which I applied for. I got the feedback, that I was too technical for this role, and that any individual in this role would be purely a manager. The individual they did hire, has now been in the job for about 6 months, and he has gotten one of these very expensive and technical courses.

To summarise the problem, it makes it very difficult to justify any kind of pay rise, if on paper I am unqualified for my current job, especially as any pay rise has to go through HR, who always ask why I'm unqualified. As I have missed out on potentially up to $40,000 of training, (which is a non-monetary benefit everyone except me is getting), I feel disrespected. I also feel that as these are the industry standard, I will eventually be limited (within this organisation), or it already has limited me, if I look for a job elsewhere.

Is there any suggestions on how I should be handling this? or is it time to tell this organisation where to go?

Comment: Have you ASKED anyone for these courses? They sound very much like goals that should be written up in your annual assessment.

Comment: Yes, I have been EXTREMELY vocal about this, and I have had them written up in my annual assessments. They have always had some excuse or another (e.g. someone needs it more than I do)

Comment: @PeteCon, the excuse they gave me for the non-technical manager getting on the course, is that he is being paid more than me, so he gets priority over me for any training. As it is more 'economically viable' for me to sit around twiddling my thumbs than it is for him. Despite his alleged non-technical requirement.

Comment: It's time to look for a job elsewhere.

Comment: Why are you still there?

Comment: @Kilisi, well as of yet, it hasn't limited me within the organisation (unless you count the managerial position I didn't get). I have still managed to get promotions, and/or pay rises, every year. They mostly tell me, I don't get training because I am already 'too knowledgeable', and other people need it more. Having said that, this thing with the 'non-technical' manager, I feel is extremely disrespectful.

Comment: `My job is a very technical one, and to be 'qualified' to do the job I am doing (according to my organisation), I am actually required to complete a number of SANS courses.` - If they're not giving you the training then it obviously isn't a requirement. What problem are you trying to solve? You say the training is required, but they're not offering it to you, yet you're doing the job. It isn't clear to me what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: you have missed up to $40,000 worth of training and certification, thats a pretty big limiter over a career.

Comment: @joeqwerty The problem is, it makes it very difficult to justify any kind of pay rise, if on paper I am unqualified for my current job, especially as any pay rise has to go through HR, who always ask why I'm unqualified. Also as Kilisi said, I have missed out on up to $40,000 of training, that will eventually limit me (within this organisation), or it already has limited me, if I look for a job elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for providing that additional info @user69953. Could you [edit] it into your question as well so you have a more cohesive story?

Comment: @StephanBranczyk Thanks, I took your advice, and another organisation snapped me up almost immediately, offering more money, and have promised to send me on courses.

Comment: Did you at least consider asking your employer to buy books for you? If your job is software related, consider also publishing on http://github.com/ or http://gitlab.com/ some open source software that you write from home (on your personal laptop)

Answer (score 4):

> They mostly tell me, I don't get training because I am already 'too knowledgeable', and other people need it more.

A fair argument in most cases. It usually doesn't make sense to send someone for a training if they're already an expert. But it's different if there's a certification or some other type of recognition tied to it. It's reasonable to pursue those to improve your resume, especially if it's a well-known and asked-for industry standard certification.

> any pay rise has to go through HR, who always ask why I'm unqualified

Well that's a bigger problem. Your company shouldn't be using you not having taken these trainings as an argument in salary discussions while they're at the same time refusing to give you that training. You do mention you still had pay raises so if you're being fairly compensated it may just be something the HR drone is conditioned to ask but that doesn't affect you.

Ordinarily I'd still recommend having a big picture conversation to figure out what's going. You explain that you'd like to follow this training for [reasons], HR seems to want you trained, and plenty of other people are being sent on multiple trainings. Explain that you've asked repeatedly for this yet somehow are always skipped and that it's giving you serious concerns. Pause there and see what they say, then take the conversation from there.

However, if this has been going on for years then I'm not sure there's any need to guess at the reasons. It would seem that your company has no intention to send you on this training. In general, believe what people are telling you about themselves and the way they operate. Assume that you'll never receive this training while in this job. Then go from there. Four years is also a health length of time to have on your resume.

If you do start a job search, be prepared to talk about your lack of these trainings if they are indeed a known industry standard. Make absolutely sure you can talk about this without seeming bitter! You should also definitely ask about the training program and budget for a new role to fit these trainings in.